# Primitive not gate with more than one input

Tags: verilog

I came found this example when reading a [Verilog article](https://technobyte.org/gate-level-modeling-in-Verilog), in which it discusses about a `not` gate with two inputs.
Is there anyone here who can explain what this means?

```
module buf_not_gates (input a, b, output c, d);
  buf (c, a, b); // c is the output, a and b are inputs
  not (d, a, b); // d is the output, a and b are inputs
endmodule

module buf_not_gates_tb;
  reg a, b;
  wire c, d;
  buf_not_gates Instance0 (a, b, c,d);
  initial begin
    a = 0; b = 0;
    #1 a = 0; b = 1; 
    #1 a = 1; b = 0;
    #1 a = 1; b = 1;
  end
  initial begin
    $monitor ("T=%t| a=%b |b=%b| c(buf)=%b |d(not)=%b", $time, a, b, c, d);
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in that code are incorrect. The `not` gate does not have 2 inputs; neither does `buf`.  According to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 28.5 *buf and not gates*:

> These two logic gates shall have **one input** and one or more outputs.
> The last terminal in the terminal list shall connect to the input of
> the logic gate, and the other terminals shall connect to the outputs
> of the logic gate.

In this line of code:

```
buf (c, a, b);
```

`b` is the only input to the `buf` instance; `c` and `a` are outputs.

It looks like the article author mistakenly copied the code from the `bufif_notif_gates` example.